# In OSX 10.9, Apache is using a different php.ini then terminal. How do I change which one terminal uses?

Tags: php, macos, apache

I'm running OSX 10.9, and using the built in Apache/PHP install.  I used this guide to upgrade the PHP from 5.4 to 5.6.

When I do a phpinfo() and run it in a browser, it shows that PHP 5.6 is running using a php.ini file located somewhere within /usr/local/...

When I run php -i in terminal, it shows that PHP 5.4 is running using a php.ini file located within somewhere within /etc/...

How do I get terminal to use the same install of PHP as Apache?

Thanks in advance!

Edited: According to comments.

Comment: do you really want 2 different versions of PHP to use the same ini? what I typically do in cases like this, is to separate common configuration (such as modules) out into other files into a directory that is scanned by both versions.

Comment: alternatively, just use *the same* PHP install for both CLI and Apache.

Comment: I guess that is what my question is.  How do I use the same PHP install for both?  I want both to use the 5.6 install.

Comment: you should then edit your question to reflect that. If you installed PHP 5.4 then first remove it, then you may need to adjust your `$PATH`.

Comment: I asked the question to the best of my understanding of the situation.  I've edited the question to reflect your input.  I didn't install PHP 5.4, it was pre-installed.  In what way does the path need adjusted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running from the Terminal.app you will either need to specify which PHP version you want to use:

```
/usr/local/php5/bin/php -i
```

Or add the new one to your `PATH`:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

Check [this page](http://php-osx.liip.ch) under FAQ for more info.

Comment: This is what most things I've found online have said, except they said to update the path in .bash_profile, which is what I did.  I will try using the .profile instead.  Here's a screenshot, am I doing this right?
http://imgur.com/FxVdSFT

Comment: No thats not right, the PHP binary will most likely not be in the `lib` directory. Try it with `bin` instead.

Comment: Bingo.  I award you 1,000 Internet points!  Your help has been much appreciated!